# Minimization of the difference between two functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am stuck with the following problem. I need to find the point on the line passing through $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ that is closest to the line through $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$

Please do not give full solution. A reasonable hint would much help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just write the equation between two arbitrary points on each line and minimize it (I assume you know calculus 101).

Comment: What do you mean by the equation between two arbitrary points? I mean I dont remember that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, what you need to do is to write down the parametrization of two lines ( w.r.t $s,t$) and determine the value of $s,t$. An observation is suppose the point $P_1$ on line $l_1$, $P_2$ on line $l_2$ which gives the minimum distance, then $\vec{P_1P_2}$ must perpendicular to two direction vectors. Hence what you need to do is to take inner product with $u_1, u_2$, obtain two linear equations, solve for $t,s$ and then you get the points.

---

Following is a proof of the fact:

Let $P_1$ on line $l_1$ with tangent vector $u_1$, $P_2$ on line $l_2$ with tangent vector $u_2$ giving the minimum distance. Then $l_1$ can be written as $P_1+tu_1$,$l_2$ can be written as $P_2+su_2$.

Let $d(t,s)=|| (P_1+tu_1)-(P_2+su_2)||^2$. Then $(0,0)$ must be a local minimum of $d$. set$\nabla d(0,0)=\vec 0$, you get the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate a little about why in the proof you wrote $l_1$ can be written as $P_1+tu_1$ I can't follow that line. And also why does it follow from the fact that if the points $$P_1 and P_2$$ gives the minimum distance, then $$P_1P_2$$ must be perpendicular in two direction vectors?

Comment: @primenumber57 A line is determined by a point it passes and a direction vector. You can find an example [here](http://mathinsight.org/line_parametrization_examples). For the second question, two vectors $v,u$ are perpendicular iff $$<v,u>=0$$. And all the other reasons are given in the proof.